# Output of Java Code

Tags: java, string

The following code :

```
public class Sample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = 2+2+"ABC"+2+3+"DEF"+4+5+"GHI"+"JKL"+6; 
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

The output of the code is

```
Output: 4ABC23DEF45GHIJKL6
```

Can someone please help me understand the output as the first two integers are added and the rest are considered as strings.

Comment: Because it was an int before you add an string to it, then its an string

Comment: because Java just executes the code from left to right in your case, so 2+2 is 4 and then you add 4 to the string "ABC" and the output is a string and stays that way.

Comment: because you are adding integers, you should concatenate them like this "2"+"2"

Comment: Reasonable question (although it could be condensed slightly) if you've spent your formative years using sane languages like C++. Have an upvote.

Comment: I don't think need downvote this question. When I come to the first language is C++. I have the same problem with @Learner. Use bracket `()` between expression to get a result from your want. The almost comment explained. You should know that concept because it relates to many cases in the real application.

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestions @vanloc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String s = 2+"ABC";

  // This will convert int 2 to String and add it to variable s

String s = 2+2+"ABC";

  // This will sum up 2's and then add them to String. This is because java
  // is read from left to right, and you can add logic in variable initialization

String s = 2+(2+"ABC");

  // This should work as you want it
```

Answer (score 2):

The `+` evaluates its arguments from left to right.

So your expression is equivalent to

`String s = ((((((((((2+2)+"ABC")+2)+3)+"DEF")+4)+5)+"GHI")+"JKL")+6);`

As you can see, the innermost expression will be an `int` type.

But when the compiler sees `4 + "ABC"`, it will switch over to string *concatenation*.

Pernicious, isn't it?!